# Filter functions: How to search multiple keys in an Objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a filter that allows user to search multiple keys: type, secondarySkillAreas._id, primarySkillAreas_id, prices and location on a arrayOf object. For example, if user check "New York" and "Conferences", it will provide the result include the `{location: 'New York'}`, and `{type: 'Conference'}`.

I now created a filter function that user can only search a single key. When user first checked "New York", it will only provide the object includes [`{location: 'New York'}`], the `type` result is not filtered.

I am using React for my app. I am thinking to store the select keys `location, skills, type, and price` in a state. and loop through these keys.

```
  const [selectedFields, setSelectField] = useState([
    'location',
    'price',
    '__t',
    'price',
    'skills'
  ]); // store all the select fields: type, secondarySkillAreas._id, primarySkillAreas_id, prices and location
```

This is the data I need to search:

```
        {
            "primarySkillAreas": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d3a0a55ab453ccf9118d92a",
                    "name": "123",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "secondarySkillAreas": [
                {
                    "primarySkillAreaReferences": [],
                    "_id": "5d371cd3b5ee253e0b5c4f09",
                    "name": "Secondary Skills",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "previousAttendees": [],
            "__t": "Book",
            "reviews": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d41f45be3a9e50f483ed493",
                    "rating": 1,
                    "review": ""
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5d41f45be3a9e50f483ed492",
            "name": "foo1",
            "url": "https://www.regextester.com/93652",
            "startingPdsaTier": 1,
            "cost": {
                "currency": "CAD",
                "minCost": "50070",
                "maxCost": "6060606",
                "groupPricingAvailable": false
            },
            "visible": true,
            "comments": "",
            "institution": {
                "_id": "5d30e7674ef04d5f6fa6856d",
                "name": "U of B",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "location": "New York, USA, NY",
            "deliveryMethod": "in-class",
            "ongoing": false,
            "duration": "5 years",
            "primarySkillAreaSortKey": "123",
            "secondarySkillAreaSortKey": "Secondary Skills",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "primarySkillAreas": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d3a0a55ab453ccf9118d92a",
                    "name": "123",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "secondarySkillAreas": [
                {
                    "primarySkillAreaReferences": [],
                    "_id": "5d371cd3b5ee253e0b5c4f09",
                    "name": "Secondary Skills",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "previousAttendees": [],
            "__t": "Subscription",
            "reviews": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d41f45ce3a9e50f483ed495",
                    "rating": 1,
                    "review": ""
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5d41f45ce3a9e50f483ed494",
            "name": "Hello World",
            "url": "https://www.regextester.com/93652",
            "startingPdsaTier": 1,
            "cost": {
                "currency": "CAD",
                "minCost": "50070",
                "maxCost": "6060606",
                "groupPricingAvailable": false
            },
            "visible": true,
            "comments": "",
            "institution": {
                "_id": "5d30e7674ef04d5f6fa6856d",
                "name": "U of A",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "location": "New York, USA, NY",
            "deliveryMethod": "in-class",
            "ongoing": false,
            "duration": "5 years",
            "primarySkillAreaSortKey": "123",
            "secondarySkillAreaSortKey": "Secondary Skills",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

But I have no idea how to modify my current filter function.

The functions are what I have currently:

```
const filterResult = (selectedArray, pdsaList, param, isLocation = false) => {
    if (selectedArray && pdsaItems) {
      const filterArray = pdsaList.filter(pdsa => {
        // search in lowercase and without whitespace if it is not Location
        let filteredVal = _.get(pdsa, `${param}`, '')
          .toLowerCase()
          .replace(/\s+/g, '');
        if (isLocation) {
          filteredVal = _.get(pdsa, `${param}`, '').toLowerCase();
        }
        return selectedArray.includes(filteredVal);
      });
      setIsFiltered(true); // display the filtered pdsa List
      return filterArray;
    }
    return pdsaItems;
  };

  // For location
  const handleSearch = locations => {
    const newLocations = locations.map(location => location.toLowerCase());
    const filteredLocations = filterResult(
      newLocations,
      defaultPDSA,
      'location'
    );
    if (newLocations.length > 0) {
      setPdsaItems(filteredLocations);
    }
    if (newLocations.length <= 0 && isFiltered) {
      loadDatafromServer();
      setIsFiltered(false);
    }
  };

  // General Select checkbox functions
  const handleSelect = (event, param) => {
    const { id: itemID, checked } = event.target;
    const checkedItems = [...new Set([...isChecked, itemID])];
    const checkedValues = checkedItems.map(t =>
      t.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')
    );
    setIsChecked([...isChecked, itemID]);

    if (!checked) {
      setIsChecked(prev => {
        return prev.filter(item => {
          return item !== itemID;
        });
      });
    }

    const filteredPdsa = filterResult(
      isChecked.length === 1 ? [] : checkedValues,
      defaultPDSA,
      param,
      true
    );

    if (filteredPdsa.length > 0) {
      setPdsaItems(filteredPdsa);
    }
    if (filteredPdsa.length <= 0 && isFiltered) {
      loadDatafromServer();
      setIsFiltered(false);
    }
  };
```

And this is how I call my type filter function

```
<CheckboxFilters
id={type}
name={type}
key={type}
param="__t"
/>
```

Comment: i think you must provide dummy data with same format with your actual data so we can see your location, type, etc data format to answer your question

Comment: @WilliamGunawan I am sorry. I just add the .json

Comment: For function handleSearch you just need put dummy data from result of checkbox, if you have more than one combination then add the combination example. It's will good if your code reproable, we don't need your view because your problem not in view but after view, you get the pattern data from checkbox and put data to function filterResult get the data. so it's reproable. :)

Comment: @WilliamGunawan I dont understand what you mean.